# I cant sign in to Metabase right after setting it up

Tags: jar, clojure, h2, unzip, metabase

I get metabase.jar v0.31.2, and I run it in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. I run it with this command:
`java -jar metabase.jar`
The problem is after I fill the required data and submit “take me to Metabase” button, I can’t sign in. I am sure the password is correct. I check the logs and find the error, this is its stack trace:
https://pastebin.com/mfZQEGDv

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a quick try and couldn't make it work with H2, but I created a dummy database with SQLite (eg. `/tmp/demo/dummy.db`) and it started correctly. I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and OpenJDK 1.8.0_191.

Comment: I change the database from H2 to Postgres and still have the same issue.